# Backbone.View not responding to Backbone.UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-ui

I'm building a small program to allow display of some details of a group of people. There is an option to update the details. However, the updates are not being rendered by the view:

Here is my server.js:

```
var express= require("express"),
bodyparser= require("body-parser");

var app= express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/public"));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index.jade");
});

app.listen(3002);
```

My index.jade is:

```
doctype html

link(rel="stylesheet", href="backbui.css")

#main

script(src= "jquery.js")
script(src= "underscore.js")
script(src= "backbone.js")
script(src= "laconic.js")
script(src= "moment.js")
script(src= "backbui.js")
script(src= "theapp.js")
```

My theapp.js file is:

```
var Person= Backbone.Model.extend({}),
People= Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var Genders= new Backbone.Collection(
        [
             {name: "Female", id: 1},
             {name: "Male", id: 0}
]);

var people= new People([
            {name: "John Doe", gender: Genders.get(0), birthday:
             new Date(1990, 5, 15), married: false},
            {name: "Jane Smith", gender: Genders.get(1), birthday:
             new Date(1985, 10, 10), married: true},
            {name: "Tom Smith", gender: Genders.get(0), birthday: 
             new Date(1980, 1, 20), married: true},
            {name: "Sally Fox", gender: Genders.get(1), birthday: 
             new Date(1998, 7, 31), married: false}
]);

var table= new Backbone.UI.TableView({
    model: people,  // collection can also be passed
    columns: [
        {title: "Name", content: "name"},
        {title: "Gender", content: "gender", 
         format: function(model){ return model.get("name"); }},
        {title: "Birthday", content: "birthday",
         format: function(date){ return date.toString(); }},
        {title: "Married", content: "married",
         format: function(married){ return married? "yes": "no"; }}
    ]
}); 

var sally= people.models[3];

var textbox= new Backbone.UI.TextField({
    model: sally,
    content: "name",
});

var radios= new Backbone.UI.RadioGroup({
    model: sally,
    content: "gender",
    alternatives: Genders,
    altLabelContent: "name",
});

var Appview= Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#main",

    render: function(){
            this.$el.append(table.render().el);
            this.$el.append(textbox.render().el);
            this.$el.append(radios.render().el);
            return this;
    }
});

new Appview().render();
```

I want to see real-time update of 4th name in the table viz. Sally Fox when I make changes in the textbox area. Similarly I would like to see the table gender of Sally Fox change when I make the change in the radio button.

Basically I want my Backbone.TableView to listen to changes made in other Backbone.UI widgets like Backbone.UI.RadioGroup and Backbone.UI.TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path.  Add listeners in your views to listen for when changes happen to the `people` collection.  Changes to individual models (i.e. `sally`) will also bubble up through the collection.

I'm not too familiar with Backbone.UI, but the changes would go something like this:

```
// Make the table listen to changes in the passed-in collection & re-render
// when needed
var table= new Backbone.UI.TableView({
    model: people,  // collection can also be passed
    columns: [
        {title: "Name", content: "name"},
        {title: "Gender", content: "gender", 
         format: function(model){ return model.get("name"); }},
        {title: "Birthday", content: "birthday",
         format: function(date){ return date.toString(); }},
        {title: "Married", content: "married",
         format: function(married){ return married? "yes": "no"; }}
    ],

    initialize: function() {
        // When a change event happens to the model/collection, re-render
        this.listenTo(model, 'change', this.render);
    }
});
```

You would do similar things for other views that you want to react to data changes.  The key is to have the views share the same instance of the model/collections you're changing, and then listen for specific changes.

If this doesn't get you going, post comments and/or a JSFiddle and we can make progress that way.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by Peter (above) is also correct, we can also make the changes directly in the backbone-ui.js library file:

Inside the initialize method for tableview (search for tableview in the file backbone-ui.js, find its initialize function) add:

```
this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
```

and you'll be fine. 
(You may want to add the same line inside the initialize method of the list property of backbone-ui.js file to get responsive views for lists)